# Wrong addition inputing

Tags: c, loops, input

**This is the program:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    static int x=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int i,k=n;
    for(i=0;i<k;++i)
    {
        printf("%d,%d   ",i,k);
        char s[3];
        scanf("%s\n",s);
        char st=s[1];
        if (st=='+') {++x;}
        else{--x;}
    }
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

If I enter 3, I should enter 3 strings but I have to enter an extra one.

**Sample execution:**

```
4
0,4   ++x
++x        //my problem is here, what why should I type this one?
1,4   ++x
2,4   --x
3,4   ++x
2
```

Answer (score 1):

- `char s[3];` is too short to store 3-character strings. Allocate one more element for terminating null-characters.
- `\n` in `scanf()` format string will have it read until next non-whitespace character, so it will seem to be requesting the extra input.
- You should limit length to read to avoid buffer overrun.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n;
    static int x=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int i,k=n;
    for(i=0;i<k;++i)
    {
        printf("%d,%d   ",i,k);
        char s[4]; /* allocate enough elements */
        scanf("%3s",s); /* remove \n and limit input length */
        char st=s[1];
        if (st=='+') {++x;}
        else{--x;}
    }
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @HoseinSarafrazi, If you feel the answer correclty adresses the problem, consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/684852).